Get current screen in Navigation Type-safety Jetpack Compose
Screens
@Serializable
sealed class Screen {
    @Serializable
    data object Home : Screen()

    @Serializable
    data class Profile(val name: String) : Screen()
}

Set up navigation
@Composable
fun AppNavigation(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    startDestination: Screen = Screen.Home,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()
) {
    val currentNavBackStackEntry: NavBackStackEntry? by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

    // Error
    val currentScreen: Screen = currentNavBackStackEntry?.toRoute<Screen>() ?: Screen.Home

    val navGraph = navController.createGraph(
        startDestination = startDestination,
    ) {
        composable<Screen.Home> {
            HomeScreen(onNavigateToProfile = { navController.navigate(it) })
        }
        composable<Screen.Profile> { navBackStackEntry ->
            val profile = navBackStackEntry.toRoute<Screen.Profile>()
            ProfileScreen(name = profile.name)
        }
    }

    NavHost(navController = navController, graph = navGraph, modifier = modifier)
}

I am trying get current screen from Navigation type-safety jetpack compose. But toRoute() only use with routes in nav graph.

Please replace your code with a minimal reproducible example so we can try it out ourselves. Make sure it is executable and exhibits the problem you describe.

Please include what you are planning on doing with currentScreen - are you trying to compare it to something else?

@ianhanniballake My temporary solusion is compare string currentNavBackStackEntry?.destination?.route to Screen::class.qualifiedName. Is there any other way to get the current screen with type Screen

You haven't actually answered my question - where are you actually using the current screen? Your code still doesn't actually do anything with this information. Please include that code.

u need usecase for currentScreen? uhm, tittle TopAppBar, navigation conditional...

"u need usecase for currentScreen? uhm, tittle TopAppBar, navigation conditional..." -- you know the "current screen" inside your nav graph. Inside the composable<Screen.Home> lambda, you know that the "current screen" is Screen.Home, for example. There, you can update state as needed to affect changes to elements outside of the nav graph, such as some overall title bar caption. I suspect this is why Ian is asking for you to show the code that would depend upon currentScreen -- it feels like there are other solutions.

Function hasRoute() can help you with the current screen like this:
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()

navBackStackEntry?.destination?.let { currentDestination ->
    shouldShowAppBar = !currentDestination.hasRoute(Settings::class)
}


Note that you need to import androidx.navigation.NavDestination.Companion.hasRoute. For some reason the IDE doesn't find the import easily, which makes it seem like the function doesn't exist.

Not beautiful, but works for now.
@Serializable
sealed class Screen(@StringRes val title: Int, val showAppBar: Boolean = true) {
    @Serializable
    data object Home : Screen(R.string.app_name)
    @Serializable
    data object Login : Screen(R.string.app_name, showAppBar = false)
}

val backStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentScreen = backStackEntry?.destination?.let {
    when (it.route) {
        Screen.Login::class.qualifiedName -> Screen.Login
        else -> Screen.Home
    }
} ?: Screen.Home

Scaffold(
   topBar = {
        if (currentScreen.showAppBar) {
            AppBar()
        }
   },
)


Be careful with this approach, I see it failing when the code is obfuscated and the class names are different.

@EuryPérezBeltré any better solution for it?

@Viks you can use the hasRoute function in the destination object.
